# Delphi: Is this code a correct procedure of nulling a pointer in FormClose?

Tags: delphi, pointers, delphi-xe6

IDE: Delphi XE6.

My main form creates another form and that form creates an instance of `TFormZoom`. All seems to work flawlessly.

I just want to be sure my procedure of nulling a pointer in `FormClose` is not distorting some inner workings of Delphi.

```
procedure TFormZoom.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := caFree;

  // if I did not set it to nil here, the next time I would create this form I would get
  // EAccessViolation, because my other code checks for this form <> nil ...

  FormZoom := nil;
end;
```

I am now thinking about, whether this approach is good. I don't get any compilation, nor run-time errors, this question is just a technicality.

Comment: Pro tip, don't use the form global variables, delete them in the global var section, if a form is using another form, the variable should be defined in the form class. And to answer  your question, yes you are doing it correctly.

Comment: I agree with whosrdaddy. Don't use the global form variables generated by the Delphi IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set a breakpoint at the `end;` of `TFormZoom.FormClose`, and use F8 to step into the VCL code that called your `onclose` event handler, you'll see that it was called from `TCustomForm.DoClose` which was previously called from `TCustomForm.Close`. At that point in time, the following code can be seen (in Delphi 10.2.3)

```
DoClose(CloseAction);
if CloseAction <> caNone then
if Application.MainForm = Self then Application.Terminate
else if CloseAction = caHide then Hide
else if CloseAction = caMinimize then WindowState := wsMinimized
else Release;
```

Because you set the Action var to `caFree`, it means the form's `.Release` will be called by the VCL code. My conclusion is: setting the global var FormZoom to nil, will not cause any problems.

Answer (score -3):

Sometimes OnClose event may not fire at all. So apart from setting 
`Action := caFree;`
I would move other code into either OnCloseQuery or OnDestroy events.

```
FormZoom := nil;
```

must be in OnDestroy event in my opinion, because there may be some other events, on controls for example, which would run during close down and cause access violation, if the form variable is already nil.